# SQLite does not create an index

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, database-migration

I am working on some database migrations in Laravel 5.4. The migrations work fine with a MySQL database, but for testing I want to use SQLite but the migration fails. Here's the code

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('mapped_venues', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('upload_job_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('venue')->default('');
            $table->unsignedInteger('venue_id')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index(['venue']);
        });

        Schema::create('mapped_teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('upload_job_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('team')->default('');
            $table->unsignedInteger('team_id')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index(['team']);
        });
    }
```

When I run `php artisan migrate` the index on the `mapped_teams.team` column is not created, but the one on `mapped_venues.venue` is!!

```
$ sqlite3 database/database.sqlite 
SQLite version 3.19.3 2017-06-08 14:26:16
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .indexes mapped_teams
sqlite> .indexes mapped_venues
mapped_venues_venue_index
sqlite>
```

I have also tried to create the indexes on a separate call

```
Schema::table('mapped_venues', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->index(['venue']);
        });
Schema::table('mapped_teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->index(['team']);
        });
```

But the result is the same. Interestingly though, when (by mistake) I left the creation of the index `$table->index['team'])` inside the call to create the table (so, I have two calls to create the index) I get the error that the index `mapped_teams_team_index` already exists.

I am using:

- Laravel 5.4.36
- Doctrine DBal 2.6.2
- SQLite 3.19.3

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have small mistake when calling the index function (used it as an array instead of a function):

```
    $table->index['venue'];
```

should be:

```
    $table->index('venue');
```

Comment: Thanks @inet123, that was just a typing mistake on the question. The actual code is fine. I have edited the question though.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually found out that the index was indeed created. I had another migration to rename the `team` column to `mapped_team`, and I wanted to remove the index first

```
Schema::table('mapped_teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropIndex(['team']);
    $table->renameColumn('team', 'mapped_team');
    $table->index(['mapped_team']);
}
```

The line where the index is dropped complained that the index `mapped_teams_team_index` didn't exist. I have modified my migration to not drop and recreate the index, but just rename it. The result is that the index named `mapped_teams_team_index` still exists but it now, correctly, indexes the `mapped_team` column. This works on both Mysql and SQLite.